# vector::clear() cost so much time?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I ran a profiler (very sleepy) on my program and it shows a high percentage on my reset function (the reset function runs per-frame).
The programs looks like this:

Init Section:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> VecOfVecOfPath;
VecOfVecOfPath.resize(20); 
for(int i=0; i<20; i++) VecOfVecOfPath.reserve(640);
```

VecOfVecOfPath is a series of path found by other functions.
VecOfVecOfPath[i] will be filled during execution, per-frame.
E.g. It is `push_back`-ed by other functions, and reset before using, per-frame.

The reset function:

```
void Reset()
{
for(int i=0; i<20; i++) VecOfVecOfPath[i].clear();
}
```

So the reset is very simple, but it do have a pretty high ranking in profiler.

Is this common? Does vector::clear() do have such overheads even for built-in type vectors?

Thanks!

---

I tried build the program in Release mode and then the cost reduced to almost zero.
From 12~13% to 0.03~0.04%.

Then I went to the source code of  and there are defines like ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL effecting extra operations in Debug mode.

So it is like @noggin182 suggested, things are different in Debug and Release mode.

Quote: "Meke sure you are profiling in release build and search to see if there are any preprocessor conditional defines you set to boost performance. – noggin182 Jan 3 at 15:32"

Comment: Have you considered that you are calling `clear` unnecessarily ?

Comment: @parapurarajkumar - first thing that occurred to me, too.  I think we need more details of the use of 'VecOfVec'  - maybe the Vecs can be recycled to avoid the clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "unnecessarily"? Unnecessarily clear even if I dont need to clear them?

Comment: It's a vec of vec of temporary path, so it is cleared and refilled per-frame.

Comment: What is a temporary path?  C++ classes cannot have spaces in their names.  What class is it, and what does its destructor look like?

Comment: The cost of `clear` is precisely the cost of the destructor calls. Check if *those* are expensive, too.

Comment: @Marson: does the destructor of "temporay path" also show up in the profiler? If you have a debugger, you could try "stack shots" rather than the profiler - just interrupt the program while it's running and see where you end up. If the program is spending a high percentage of time in `clear`, then a high percentage of your interruptions will be in `clear`.

Comment: @blackbear: becoz I need VecOfVec to be size of 20, only VecOfVec[i] should be cleared

Comment: sorry all, it's a vector of vector of int, my bad; path is the meaning of it, not type

Comment: @Marson: in that case something's definitely odd. `std::vector<int>::clear()` should be equivalent to either `__end_ptr == __start_ptr` or `__size = 0`, where those are data members. Hence it should be very fast, you shouldn't notice calling it 20 times per frame (well, not compared with putting those 20*640 elements into the vectors each frame).

Comment: @SteveJessop: that's right, i thought the Reset should be very fast, too. Somehow it do has a high ranking. All I can think of preventing unnecessary calling of clear() is to use another 20 flags indicating invalid pathes, then clear() is no need for invalid ones.

Comment: You could maybe keep another VecOfVec, initialized with 20 'invalid' paths and initialize the 'live' VecOfVec with NULLs.  When you want to load a Vec, copy its reference across to the 'live' VecOfVec.  When you want to 'clear' it, set the 'live' VecOfVec back to NULL.  Saves having to manage a separate bool array.

Comment: @Marson: I don't think you should add complexity, or anyway not yet. At the very least, single-step through a call to `clear`, preferably in disassembly, and see whether it really is doing any work. If it isn't, then setting a flag won't actually save any runtime. If it is, there should be some rational explanation: in any serious C++ implementation, it would be a bug for such a trivial library operation to genuinely be slow.

Comment: I suppose perhaps the implementation of `vector` relies on the optimizer to remove a do-nothing loop. You have switched on optimization, right?

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'll try release build with optimize later in this morning and report results, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what is in your vector, if your nested vectors contain classes then you will be invoking the d'tor for each instance in the nested vectors. I'm quite sure it will also be deallocating memory.

It sounds like you are writing a game? If so a few books (PDFs) I've read on game writing suggest that vector is good for general use but you will be better off NOT using it for games. Just use native arrays and manage the memory yourself or roll your own container class.

Is 640 the upper-bound of your vector? Would you be better of perhaps using something like this?

```
sometype Values[20][640];
int size[20];
```

Then your reset call could just be

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++) size[0] = 0;
```

You will still even be able to use any stl functions like this:

```
std::sort(Values[i], Values[i] + size[i]);
```

That's about as much help as I can provide without any more information

Comment: it's of type int, so i thought it wouldnt take much time on clear()-ing it. And I thought native arrays are the same as vectors if I correctly reserve() for it? Then vectors wont do re-allocation so it's fast.

Comment: ok, if it is an int vector then I would have thought this shouldn't be that slow. What compiler are you using? I've not look at all implementations of vector but I was surprised how different they were between MSVC, Borland and GCC. They all have switches too to enable certain sanity and debug checks and perform tasks like range checking and masking sure you only use iterators on the container they are meant for. Meke sure you are profiling in release build and search to see if there are any preprocessor conditional defines you set to boost performance.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 professional. I'll try release build later this morning and report result, thanks!

Comment: This is the answer: "Meke sure you are profiling in release build and search to see if there are any preprocessor conditional defines you set to boost performance. – noggin182"

Comment: The advice to "just use native arrays" is absolute snake oil for inexperienced devs.  It's likely not the STL, but _how you're using it_ that's the problem.  If you really think the STL is a significant source of performance problems, try [EASTL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html), which was specifically written with the performance enhancements that some people wish the STL had.  __But__, before you even bother with that, try absolutely everything else, because _it's extremely unlikely_ extra overhead in the STL is __the source__ of your performance issues.

Comment: I would stronly advice against not using the stl. You can use vectors and use reserve() when you create them to prevent multiple resizings, and it acts almost as an array except that you don't have to remember to delete it. As for the original problem, it shouldn't happen if you are compiling with optimizations (release mode)!